# Skype 4.2 crashes when connecting to one specific person

Tags: crash, skype

ok i have Skype 4.2 on Windows Vista 32 bit.  Skype was working fine with no problems at all but a situation came up and i had to reformat my laptop.

Since the reformat Skype doesn't connect to just one person on my contacts list.  Ive uninstalled reinstalled multiple times, even removed him from my contacts and re-added but to no avail.  He is on Skype mobile with his phone not sure if this is a prob as it wasn't before.

Answer (score 1):

Advice: Contact Skype support. That's the only way I guess to work this around. (After you filled out the form and you wait, you can give a try to [Skype portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/skype_portable).)